# View both assembly and source lines from Instruments?

Tags: c, macos, profiling, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to profile some difficult code in Instruments and need to see both assembly and the source code lines. Is there any way to switch views? The only way I know of is to not compile the program with `-g` so that there are no debug tables.. but it'd be extremely useful to see both on one screen where each set of assembly instructions are also marked as what line they actually implement in the source code.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version of Instruments that comes with Xcode 6, when you are in the source view, there is a set of five small buttons above the source code you are viewing. Click the second button to show both the source code and disassembly views.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I swear I remember looking in that area and not seeing those buttons!

Comment: When I tried to view trace details from another Mac, these five small buttons were disabled. How can I go forward?

Comment: @NehaVipin The buttons are not disabled for me. Ask a new question showing what you are doing in Instruments, including the instrument you are using for profiling. Describe the problem you are having in more detail. Maybe someone else will have a solution for you.

Comment: I was profiling app from Xcode and I hadn't created .ipa before profiling. Once I completed, leak testing, I saved the trace file and when I opened it from another Mac, it cannot link with a .dsym file. So I was unable to have the buttons enabled.

Comment: For me the source always says "unavailable"

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie Ask a new question about your issue.